# Kendo UI grid: custom k-grouping-header text configuration

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

When using the jQuery approach to set a custom grouping header message (EDIT: recommended by the KENDO UI support staff on these forums in the past), e.g.

```
    $(".k-grouping-header").html("my custom grouping message");
```

the custom message reverts to the standard message if a user drags a column-header to the group header and then clicks the (X) to remove the grouping.

Is there a way to set this custom message as part of the grid's configuration so it will survive the group/degroup operation?

To be clear, I have a custom message in mind, as distinct from a localized message; for example, "Drag the [department] column-header here to group by department" if department is the only column on the grid that is set to be groupable. The message would vary from grid to grid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation you could use.

```
groupable: {
    messages: {
        empty: "Custom message text"
    }
}
```

The documentation has gotten rather good latelly.

Comment: How do you set groupable to true and include the message?

Comment: Apparently, when the custom message is set, it is not necessary to set groupable: true. The presence of the messages object suffices.

Comment: Any ideas on how to set the grouped headers messages themselves so they're not prefixed?  ie, instead of displaying `category: Beverages` just say `Beverages`?  The documentation on `groupable.messages` is blank.  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-groupable.messages

Comment: for persian message ://groupable: true,
                groupable: {        
                 messages: {
          empty: "برای گروه بندی بر اساس ستون روی عنوان ستون مربوطه کلیک کرده و به اینجا بکشید"
        }
      },
    //noRecords: true,
    noRecords: {
       template: "هیچ رکوردی موجود نیست"
     },